# C# Com server global register

Tags: c#, com

I use this class:

```
    [ComVisible(true)]
[Guid("DA27DEC3-6B10-452E-B9B0-0AAC8C86D232")]
[ProgId("GameCheater.COM.RegisterManager")]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
public class RegisterManager : IRegister
{
    public RegisterManager()
    {

    }

    ~RegisterManager()
    {

    }
    [ComVisible(true), Description("Description of this Element")]
    public bool IsRegister(string address)
    {
       return RegisterPull.dictionary.TryGetValue(address, out _);
    }
    [ComVisible(true), Description("Description of this Element")]
    public void Register(string address)
    {
        var clientDetails = new ClientDetails()
        {
            Address = address,
            LastRegister = DateTime.Now
        };

        if (RegisterPull.dictionary.ContainsKey(address))
            RegisterPull.dictionary[address] = clientDetails;
        else
            RegisterPull.dictionary.TryAdd(address, clientDetails);
    }
}
```

The RegisterPull.dictionary is static:

```
 public static class RegisterPull
{
    public static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, ClientDetails> dictionary =
        new ConcurrentDictionary<string, ClientDetails>();
}
```

This is first start the aplication:
I register the "daa" and i received the response true. https://prnt.sc/gYP2Z5-hYjRo
The problem:
After i close the application and run again the isRegister will return false;

The Question:
Is posible to register this class global?

The idea is:
I wanna register from c# class and i need the result in c++.

Is this possible? I don't like to use storage like sql or ..

Comment: The content of a ConcurrentDictionary disappears in smoke when you restart your program.  You would need a dbase or a file for persistent storage.

Comment: Or, you can implement your COM server inside its own process. When COM clients obtain the server interface and then release it, the server can stay running so future clients can access it without restarting it each time.