# C++ creating an instance of a COM class

Tags: c++, com, ole

I use this code:

EDIT:

```
interface __declspec(uuid("{325ADA34-FF89-4AAB-BB14-A81A07F8C791}")) IRegister : public IDispatch
{
public:
    virtual bool IsRegister(char* address) = 0;
    virtual void Register(char* address) = 0;
};
IRegister* pBox;

  void Test1()
{
    pBox->Register("test");
    auto a = pBox->IsRegister("test");
}

extern "C"  int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR * argv[])
{

    CoInitialize(NULL);

    CLSID clsid;
    HRESULT hr1 = CLSIDFromProgID(OLESTR("GameCheater.COM.RegisterManager"), &clsid);

    HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(
        clsid,
        NULL,
        CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER,
        IID_PPV_ARGS(&pBox)
    );

    
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf("Couldn't create the instance!...");
    }
    else
    {
        Test1();
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

The handler is created, but when I try to use the class, I received this error:

[image]

This working perfect in C#:

[image]

I use this code to create the com class:

```
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [Guid("325ADA34-FF89-4AAB-BB14-A81A07F8C791")]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
    public interface IRegister
    {
        [DispId(0)]
        bool IsRegister(string address);
        [DispId(1)]
        void Register(string address);
    }
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [Guid("DA27DEC3-6B10-452E-B9B0-0AAC8C86D892")]
    [ProgId("GameCheater.COM.RegisterManager")]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    public class RegisterManager : IRegister
    {
        public bool IsRegister(string address)
        {
            return RegisterPull.dictionary.TryGetValue(address, out _);
        }

        public void Register(string address)
        {

            var clientDetails = new ClientDetails()
            {
                Address = address,
                LastRegister = DateTime.Now
            };

            if (RegisterPull.dictionary.ContainsKey(address))
                RegisterPull.dictionary[address] = clientDetails;
            else
                RegisterPull.dictionary.TryAdd(address, clientDetails);
        }

        public RegisterManager()
        {

        }

        ~RegisterManager()
        {

        }
    }
```

How I can solve the error? How can I cast the class with C++ class?

I searched for many tutorials about this, but I don't found anything.

Comment: [Why should i not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: You should check `FAILED(hr)` before you do anything else.

Comment: Yes, wrong interface declaration.  It needs to derive from at least IUnknown, possibly IDispatch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All COM interfaces derive from [`IUnknown`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/unknwn/nn-unknwn-iunknown), and sometimes from [`IDispatch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oaidl/nn-oaidl-idispatch).  Your `interface` needs to do the same, according to the requirements of the COM object you are trying to use, eg:

```
interface RegisterManager : public IUnknown { // or IDispatch
    ...
};
```

Also, `interface` methods need to be declared as *pure virtual* (ie abstract), eg:

```
public:
    virtual bool IsRegister(char* address) = 0;
    virtual void Register(char* address) = 0;
```

Also, you don't need the `InterfaceDispatcher` class just to use `__declspec(uuid)`. You can (and should) apply the `uuid` directly to the `interface`, eg:

```
interface __declspec(uuid("{325ADA34-FF89-4AAB-BB14-A81A07F8CE71}")) RegisterManager : public IUnknown {
    ...
};
```

In which case, your call to `CoCreateInstance()` can then make use of the [`IID_PPV_ARGS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-iid_ppv_args) macro, eg:

```
HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(
        clsid,
        NULL,
        CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER,
        IID_PPV_ARGS(&pBox)
    );
```

Also, you are calling `Test1()` even if `CoCreateInstance()` fails, which will cause your code to crash. Don't do that, eg:

```
HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(...);

if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    Test1();
else
    printf("Couldn't create the instance, error: 0x%08x", hr);
```

---

**UPDATE**:

Now that you have posted your C# code, I see that your `IRegister` interface is marked as `InterfaceIsIDispatch`, which means it derives from `IDispatch` rather than `IUnknown` (also, its methods are marked with `DispId`, so they are callable via the [`IDispatch.Invoke()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oaidl/nf-oaidl-idispatch-invoke) method).

Unfortunately, being marked as `InterfaceIsIDispatch` also means the methods are accessible ONLY by `IDispatch.Invoke()` (ie, late binding), so they are much more complicated to call then using the `IRegister` interface directly (ie, early binding).

Per the [`InterfaceTypeAttribute` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.interfacetypeattribute?view=net-8.0):

> By default, the [Tlbexp.exe (Type Library Exporter)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/tlbexp-exe-type-library-exporter) exposes a managed interface to COM as a dual interface, giving you the flexibility of late binding or the performance of early binding. The [`ComInterfaceType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.cominterfacetype?view=net-8.0) enumeration enables you to override the default behavior and specify late binding only or early binding only. For example, **you can apply `InterfaceType (ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)` to an interface to produce metadata to restrict callers to late binding only.** Although interfaces that derive from the `IDispatch` interface are often dual, **the `InterfaceIsIDispatch` enumeration member allows only late-bound calls to the interface methods**. This attribute has no effect on the managed view of the interface. For additional information on how interfaces are exposed to COM, see [Exported Type Conversion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/1dfe55f4-07a2-4b61-aabf-a8cf65783a6b(v=vs.100)).

So, for example (error handling omitted for brevity):

```
IDispatch* pBox;

void Test1()
{
    VARIANTARG arg;
    VariantInit(&arg);
    V_VT(&arg) = VT_BSTR;
    V_BSTR(&arg) = SysAllocString(OLESTR("test"));

    DISPPARAMS param = {};
    param.rgvarg = &arg;
    param.cArgs = 1;

    DISPID dispid;

    //pBox->Register("test");
    LPCWSTR name = OLESTR("Register");
    pBox->GetIDsOfNames(IID_NULL, (LPOLESTR*)&name, 1, 0, &dispid);
    pBox->Invoke(dispid, IID_NULL, 0, DISPATCH_METHOD, &param, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    //auto a = pBox->IsRegister("test");
    name = OLESTR("IsRegister");
    pBox->GetIDsOfNames(IID_NULL, (LPOLESTR*)&name, 1, 0, &dispid);
    VARIANT a;
    VariantInit(&a);
    pBox->Invoke(dispid, IID_NULL, 0, DISPATCH_METHOD, &param, &a, NULL, NULL);
    VariantClear(&a);

    VariantClear(&arg);   
}

extern "C" int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR * argv[])
{
    CoInitialize(NULL);

    CLSID clsid;
    HRESULT hr1 = CLSIDFromProgID(OLESTR("GameCheater.COM.RegisterManager"), &clsid);

    HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(
        clsid,
        NULL,
        CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER,
        IID_PPV_ARGS(&pBox)
    );
  
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf("Couldn't create the instance!...");
    }
    else
    {
        Test1();
        pBox->Release();
    }
    
    CoUninitialize();
    return 0;
}
```

Refer to [Accessing Members Through IDispatch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/automat/accessing-members-through-idispatch) for more details.

Comment: Thank you. I edited the code with your changes and i have the same error. Also i try with "IDispatch" "IUnknown". I added here the code from c#, maybe the problem is there.

Comment: Omg, you are the best :D This working perfect. And your code work global. Can you explain why? I have another question here "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75652149/c-sharp-com-server-global-register" about global  .. they told me to use database but your code is working... if i open the application again the isRegister return true; This is more then perfect.

Comment: @AlexSoryn your use of `CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER` when getting the COM server interface implies that the COM server is running in its own separate EXE process, and thus it can stay running after your C++ code has released the interface.